# Transactions with lb4 and mysql

Tags: mysql, transactions, backend, loopback

I have a backend with loopback 4 and a database in mysql, I am handling transactions exactly as the official documentation indicates, the problem is that when the transaction fails for any reason, the id that is autoincrementable in the database is lost and automatically when another transaction is registered and it is successful the id has no sequence, that is to say, in a few words, I generate ghost records in the database.

My model:
[image: My model]

My repository:
[image: My repository]

My controller:
[image: My controller]

DB:
[image: DB]

Comment: Autoincrement ids are not supposed to be sequential and gapless, just unique, so this behaviour is both expected and nothing you should worry about. Or are those "ghost records" persistent?